# How to draw a drop shadow on ellipse?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, shadow

`g.FillEllipse(Pens.Black, ClientRectangle.X, ClientRectangle.Y, 60, 60);`
This is my code of ellipse.
So I want to make transparent shadow for it, with adjustable size of shadow if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ready-made drop shadow in `winforms` but you can get a nice effect by drawing a few semitransparent ellipses before drawing the real one:

[image]  [image] [image]

Don't let the code fool you: The drop shadow is effectively created by only three lines.

```
private void panel1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    Color color = Color.Blue;
    Color shadow = Color.FromArgb(255, 16, 16, 16);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80 - i * 10, shadow)))
        { g.FillEllipse(brush, panel1.ClientRectangle.X + i*2, 
                               panel1.ClientRectangle.Y + i, 60, 60); }
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color))
        g.FillEllipse(brush, panel1.ClientRectangle.X, panel1.ClientRectangle.Y, 60, 60);

    // move to the right to use the same coordinates again for the drawn shape
    g.TranslateTransform(80, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(80 - i * 10, shadow), 2.5f))
        { g.DrawEllipse(pen, panel1.ClientRectangle.X + i * 1.25f,
                             panel1.ClientRectangle.Y + i, 60, 60); }
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(color))
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, panel1.ClientRectangle.X, panel1.ClientRectangle.Y, 60, 60);

}
```

Note that for non-black colors you will usually want to use either black or gray or a very dark hue of that color..

Note that your code doesn't work as posted: You can only draw with a pen or fill with a brush!

Comment: I have an array of PictureBox and and am drawing on the picture box using this method, can you help me add a box shadow to the color being passed to the brush?
```Pen mypen = new Pen(color, 3);
            SolidBrush mybrush = new SolidBrush(color);
            //after drawing the ellipse
           // drawCircle(e.Graphics, mypen, this.center_x, this.center_y, this.radii);
            //you need to fill it
            double radius = this.radii / 1.8;
            fillCircle(e.Graphics, mybrush, this.center_x, this.center_y,(float) radius);```